# combo box functions like selected item or combo box find string not working properly

Tags: c#, combobox

Combo box is not working properly,but some windows form it will return the index value when we find string,but some windows form it wont work. How can i solve this error.

//int i=combobox1.FindString("HELLO");

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: It works but then it doesn't work.  We can't solve that for you.  If it's returning -1, then the string isn't in the collection.  Post reproducible code if you want help.